# Can you import any python library in Julia?

Tags: python, julia

My doubt was can you import any python module or library in Julia and vice versa.I am just getting started with Julia language so just want to know about it.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl

Comment: The answer is no, they are completely separate ecosystems. PyCall does make it possible to have a python session within a julia session, and share variables between them.

Answer (score 7):

After quick googling, I found this site : https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl where you can call python library's functions from Julia.

**Here's a small example in using it (importing math module) :**

```
using PyCall
math = pyimport("math")
```

**You can now call functions like :** `math.sin()` etc.